# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la contraseña original de MySQL en Mac OS?

Tags: mysql, macos

¿Cómo puedo instalar MySQL en Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6? Tengo problemas para instalar MySQL y tengo rato intentando la instalación.

No puedo cambiar la contraseña original por una contraseña propia.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba, instalando MySQLWorkbench, luego:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Reinicia la pc, para que los cambios tomen efecto, y en MySQLWorkbench puedes cambiar la contraseña.